# How to trigger/orchestrate stored procedure from databricks?

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, databricks, orchestration

I have ETL pipeline in Databricks (10.x) that does the following:

**ETL**

1. Reads from lake
2. Loads data frame to Azure database
3. Issue: Merges data into data model (SQL Proc)
4. Updates Water mark

**What is the issue?**

- Databricks is expensive to run while SQL Proc is running so I'd like queue/trigger proc instead of running.

I could use ADF but I really don't want to do it.

**Short term solution:**

- I plan to run proc step using cheapest cluster to reduce cost for now.

**Possible solution:**

I plan to create a trigger on a log table. Log table will call merge statement. I think it could work. I will update once I implement.

Comment: Do you want to complete the entire process (4 steps) without having to use databricks cluster?

Comment: Ideally, I want to complete step3 without databricks cluster.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. You don't want to run Stored procedure from databricks notebook/cluster as it is costly compared to other steps. Can you try using logic apps instead? Or do you want to complete this without using any other services?

Comment: Correct. Currently, I try not to introduce additional services.

Comment: As far as I know, to do any operation in Databricks, a cluster will be utilized. Your short-term solution might be better option if you don't want to use external services. Since it is just ETL, you can consider completing all the steps directly in ADF.